# submit a path like /home/ahmad/local

Tags: php, restler, swagger

Hi Restler/Swagger friends

There is a problem when i post a url like: /home/ahmad/local

it returns the following error:

```
Request URL

http://s1/RestlerUpdate/complextypestests/_url/%2Fhome%2Fahmad%2Flocal

Response Body
   [unable to parse as json; raw response below]

Not Found

The requested URL /RestlerUpdate/complextypestests/_url//home/ahmad/local was not found on this server.

Response Code
404
```

How can i submit a url without using encoding??

my test code is:

```
class Type{
   /**
     * POST url
     *
     * @param string $url {@type string}
     * @return string
     */
    function post_url($url) {
        return $url;
    }
}
```

my project structure as follow:

```
myproject
  |
  ----explorer
  |
  ---vendor
  |
  ---api2params.php (contain class Type)
  |
  ---index.php
  |
  --- .htaccess
```

.htaccess as follow:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors On
</IfModule>
```

Comment: are you saying you want to post a variable called _url? Please show us the restler endpoint and it's configured route.

Comment: please do not post useless portions of code but the complete class and file location of the class.. Additionally do you use a htaccess or rewrite requests to the restler index.php in any way?

Comment: please take a look to the complete post

Comment: It looks like your mod_rewrite Rules aren't setup properly

Comment: what i should update in  mod_rewrite Rules?